# /proc/pid/mountinf file's root column meaning

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, unmount

What is the meaning of the root column in /proc/pid/mountinfo file?

As per the manual, it says

```
 (4)  root: the pathname of the directory in the filesystem which forms the root of this mount.
```

It is not very clear from the documentation. Can someone please explain this? May be with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of always mounting the root of a filesystem (e.g. `mount /dev/sda3 /mnt` would normally attach "/" of the sda3 filesystem onto /mnt), Linux allows mounting only a sub-path (subdirectory or even a file).

While there is no direct way of doing so<sup>1</sup> for a fresh mount, the most common use is **bind mounts**. For example, if you have something mounted on /mnt/a, doing `mount --bind /mnt/a/foo /mnt/b` would duplicate the mount and would set `/foo` as the root for the /mnt/b mount.

If the original device on /mnt/a was e.g. /dev/sda3, then the "root" column would show `/` for the original /mnt/a mount but `/foo` for the /mnt/b mount, and `findmnt` show `/dev/sda3[/foo]` as being mounted on /mnt/b.

(Note that bind mounts are not limited to directories – while `/mnt/a/foo` is a directory in this example, it **can also be a file**, in which case it can be mounted on top of another file.)

```
# mkdir /mnt/a
# mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/a

# mkdir /mnt/a/foo
# touch /mnt/a/foo/bar

# mkdir /mnt/b
# mount --bind /mnt/a/foo /mnt/b

# findmnt

# umount /mnt/a
# ls -la /mnt/b
```

(The two resulting mounts are equals – /mnt/b is not a "child" of the /mnt/a mount in any way, and you can unmount /mnt/a without affecting /mnt/b.)

Some filesystems such as Btrfs have custom mount options that work in a similar way; for example, Btrfs has `subvol=` – which only works for paths that indeed represent the root of a Btrfs subvolume, but at VFS level it looks the same. Mounting a Btrfs filesystem with `subvol=home` would cause `/home` to be shown as the "root" of this mount.

---

<sup>1</sup> Although util-linux 'mount' has `X-mount.subdir=`, but it achieves this by mounting the root as usual, then doing a bind mount of the desired subdirectory, then unmounting the root.

Comment: Thanks! This does clear up my doubts. One question, does this mean that if the root is "/", then it is guaranteed to be a non-bind mount. If root is anything other than "/", then it is a bind munt?

Comment: Usually, but it is **not** guaranteed – it's always possible to do `mount --bind /mnt/a /mnt/b`, both mounts will then have `/` as their root, and both mounts have equal standing (i.e. the kernel does not track that "/mnt/b is a bind mount of /mnt/a" or anything like that; it's a bit like hardlinks in that sense). And on the other hand, Btrfs subvolume mounts are certainly not bind mounts, but they still report a subdirectory as the mount root.